# Find all logback appenders configured in logback.xml even if not attached to any logger

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am building an admin UI for managing logback loggers level and changing appenders. I know I can find all appenders that are added to some logger with the following code:

```
private Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> getAppendersMap() {
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appendersMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Logger logger : loggerContext.getLoggerList()) {
      Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> appenderIterator = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
      while (appenderIterator.hasNext()) {
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = appenderIterator.next();
        if (!appendersMap.containsKey(appender.getName())) {
          appendersMap.put(appender.getName(), appender);
        }
      }
    }

    return appendersMap;
}
```

The problem is if I have this `logback.xml` as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="10 minutes">

  <appender name="writeToConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>
        %date{yyyy-MM-dd;HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-11p: %40.40c: %X{tablist}%m %n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="NOPAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.helpers.NOPAppender" />

  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="writeToConsole"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

the `NOPAppender` is **not** a attached to any logger and therefor the method `getAppendersMap()` **doesn't find it**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 plus years, I found something that can be used with Logback XML configuration:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer;
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ActionConst;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.InterpretationContext;
import ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException;

/**
 * Utility class for finding all configured logback appenders.
 */
public class LogbackAppenderFinder {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogbackAppenderFinder.class);

  private LogbackAppenderFinder() {

  }

  /**
   * Tries to find all appenders from an xml config. The method works by trying to find the default logback config file 
   * names, can be further enhanced to include others, e.g. files supported by Spring Boot or custom files.
   *
   * @return Map of all the appenders configured with the XML file where the key is the appender name configured in
   * the xml file and the value is the appender itself.
   */
  public static Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>> findAppendersFromXmlConfig() {
    try {
      LoggerContext dummyLoggerContext = new LoggerContext();
      ContextInitializer contextInitializer = new ContextInitializer(dummyLoggerContext);
      URL configurationFileUrl = contextInitializer.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(true);
      if (configurationFileUrl != null && configurationFileUrl.toString().endsWith(".xml")) {
        JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
        configurator.setContext(dummyLoggerContext);
        configurator.doConfigure(configurationFileUrl);
        InterpretationContext interpretationContext = configurator.getInterpretationContext();
        Map<String, Object> objectMap = interpretationContext.getObjectMap();
        return (Map<String, Appender<ILoggingEvent>>) objectMap.get(ActionConst.APPENDER_BAG);
      } else {
        LOGGER.warn("Unable to find xml configuration file.");
      }
    } catch (JoranException e) {
      LOGGER.warn("Failed to parse logback configuration, check config file.");
    }
    return new HashMap<>();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

When configuring itself from an external file (logback.xml, logback-test.xml, logback.groovy etc) Logback walks through the configuration like so (this is an abridged version of what it does):

- Finds any appenders
- Adds each appender to a transient `APPENDER_BAG` in `InterpretationContext.objectMap`
- For each `appender-ref` (which exists within a logger definition) look for the referenced appender (by name) in this `APPENDER_BAG` and if present then add that appender to the current logger

You can define explicit loggers with appender associations: `<logger name="com.x.y" level="INFO"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>` or use the `<root/>` element to associate appenders with all logger instances: `<root level="INFO"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></root>`.

So, appenders which are not associated with any loggers are only known about at configuration time, once the `LoggerContext` has been created the transient state (the `APPENDER_BAG`) is discarded. This explains why your `getAppendersMap()` doesn't find your `NOOPAppender`.

I *think* your requirement here is to 'know about' an appender even if it is not wanted at configuration time. Presumably, an appender could be unwanted initially but someone could choose to enable later. It's like you are trying to use logback.xml as a complete statement of all the appenders which someone *might* want to use at some point in your application's runtime. In order to do this you will have to include the optional appender in your `LoggerContext` initially but with a no-op implementation. This is sort of what you are already doing in your question but you just need to add your `NOPAppender` to the root context.

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="NOPAppender"/>
</root>
```

This will have no effect on the running system since the appender is a no-op but since it is referenced in the `LoggerContext` it is available for you to manage though of course if you want to enable this then the choice of appender class would have to be changed programmatically to something other than a no-op.

Another alternative might be to programmatically create an appender and add it to the `LoggerContext` as/when you need it.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. The intention for the tool is to be used i any application that has logback as a logger system. Because of that I can't ask everyone that will integrate the tool to add all appenders to ROOT logger. You are right that it doesn't make sense to have configured appender that is not attached to any logger but the problem in my case is that through the admin app a user can detach an appender from all loggers that are configured and the appender will be lost (or better said: I can't find it anymore with my method) and can't be assigned to any other logger afterwards.

Comment: @vl4d1m1r4 Ok, so when a user detaches an appender it is lost from the `LoggerContext` thereby making it harder for you to attach it to another logger later. Perhaps your application could retain a store of detached appenders so that they are available for programmtic attachment later. To put it another way; Logback discards the unattached appender but perhaps you should retain it within **your** application so that it remains available for subsequent attachment to another logger.